# Chartjs increase grid distance

Tags: javascript, charts

Image - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsbQV.png)

dates are displayed on the x-axis, values are displayed on the y-axis.

How can I change the interval distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the documentation of chartjs and specifically linear axis:
[chartjs documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html)

Code Example:

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/3/)

```
xAxes: [{
type: 'time',
ticks: {
    autoSkip: true,
    maxTicksLimit: 20
}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not elaborate enough. Atleast you should have given sample json for the chartjs via which you are plotting. From my understanding this should work :

```
xAxis: {
          ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 10
            }
        }
```